# Data Table stateSave refresh continues POST requests after closing dialog

Tags: datatables, xpages

I am using the Data Tables jQuery plugin on XPages to display our price list to users. The administrators of the price list search for similar items, click the item description to modify the item via a dialog box. As there are over 1000 items in the price list it is necessary to save the search and at the same time refresh the table so the user can review the changes in the list after closing before moving to the next item in their search.  Due to the large number of entries refreshing the whole page is messy, so when opening the dialog I refresh only the dialog, which has always worked fine until I have introduced the stateSave on the DataTable. The problem being now when I close the dialog the page continues making POST requests to open the dialog again with a random item from the bean.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<xp:div style="width:30%" styleClass="mg20">
    <xp:panel id="tablePanel">
                <table id="keyItemsPLTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Code</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="10000"
                        var="rowData">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#  #javascript:itemBean.getPlItems("All","Price List Sales Cat Only")}]]></xp:this.value>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xp:link escape="true"
                                    text="#{rowData.description}" id="link3">
                                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                        submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dialog1" execMode="partial"> //Problem occurs due to this partial refresh
                                        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:itemBean.setPlItem(rowData);
    var dialog = getComponent("dialog1");
    dialog.show()}]]></xp:this.action>
                                    </xp:eventHandler>
                                </xp:link>
                            </td>
                            <xp:text tagName="td" escape="true"
                                id="computedField1" value="#{rowData.code}">
                            </xp:text>
                        </tr>
                    </xp:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <xp:scriptBlock>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
         var table = $('#keyItemsPLTable').DataTable( {
             stateSave: true, //https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave
            stateDuration: -1//This doesn't seem to work. https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateDuration
            });
            });
          ]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:scriptBlock>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:div>


<xe:dialog id="dialog1">

        <xp:panel id="panelFullDialog" styleClass="mg20">
                <xp:div styleClass="mg20">
                    <xp:inputText id="inputDesc"
                        value="#{itemBean.plItem.description}" styleClass="wd200">
                    </xp:inputText>
                </xp:div>


                <xp:div styleClass="mg20">
                    <xp:inputText value="#{itemBean.plItem.code}"
                        id="inputText2" styleClass="wd200">
                    </xp:inputText>
                </xp:div>

                <xe:dialogButtonBar id="dialogButtonBar1">
                <xp:button value="Cancel" id="button4">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialog1}')]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>

                <xp:button id="button1">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[Save & Close]]></xp:this.value>
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"  refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tablePanel">
                        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:itemBean.savePLItem();
var dialog = getComponent("dialog1");
dialog.hide();

                    }]]></xp:this.action>

                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
            </xe:dialogButtonBar>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:dialog>
```

On closing the Post requests continue with the dialog reappearing until the page is closed.

200
    POST
instant.abc.co.uk   testing.xsp?$$ajaxid=view:_id1:tablePanel   xhr html    35.47 kB 426.05 kB  2165 ms
200
    POST
instant.abc.co.uk   testing.xsp?$$ajaxid=view:_id1:dialog1  xhr html    574 B   650 B   1969 ms
200
    GET 
instant.abc.co.uk   testing.xsp?$$ajaxid=view:_id1:dialog1:_content&$$showdialog=true&$$created=true&$$createdialog=false&$$viewid=!6rftmmaw860jebb294nc4ay3y!  xhr html    871 B   1.94 kB 
6 ms
200
    POST
instant.abc.co.uk   testing.xsp?$$ajaxid=view:_id1:dialog1  xhr html    574 B   650 B   2057 ms
200
    GET 
instant.abc.co.uk   testing.xsp?$$ajaxid=view:_id1:dialog1:_content&$$showdialog=true&$$created=true&$$createdialog=false&$$viewid=!6rftmmaw860jebb294nc4ay3y!  xhr html    873 B   1.94 kB 
4 ms
200
    POST
instant.networkconnect.co.uk    testing.xsp?$$ajaxid=view:_id1:dialog1  xhr html    574 B   650 B

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to refresh `tablePanel` after closing the dialog, don't make that the refresh ID. The `hide()` method takes a parameter of the area to refresh after the dialog has closed. That's because the SSJS needs to post back to the browser to make the call to close the dialog, so it will pass a client-side JavaScript call to make a GET request to refresh whatever ID was passed as a parameter of the `hide()` method. See https://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-dialog-control-and-partial-refreshes/.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that all makes sense and hopefully will speed up lots of my slow dialogs on Save. Are you able to provide an example of how I would write the code for dialog.hide() with parameters. I am not being lazy, I have tried.

Comment: If it's SSJS, you just use the id of the area you're trying to refresh, so `dialog.hide("tablePanel")`. On the browser's Network tab you should see a POST when clicking the button on your dialog, calling the server, then a GET request after the response is received when the web page retrieves the up-to-date HTML for the area you're refreshing, e.g. tablePanel.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I understand but unfortunately that does not solve the problem. The continous opening of the dialog after closing it is only prevented by removing the partial refresh and partial execution from the link opening the dialog - show(). I have them in as the dialog opens so much faster than with out it.